# Know when Facebook chats have been seen via API?

Tags: facebook, api, xmpp, chat

When two Facebook users exchange messages or chat messages, either user can see when the other has seen their most recent message.

Can an app using the `Facebook Chat API` know when chat messages have been seen, without requiring the `read_inbox` permission?