# Notify facebook chat server that a thread has been seen

Tags: facebook, xmpp, facebook-fql

This is similar to [Know when Facebook chats have been seen via API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307175/know-when-facebook-chats-have-been-seen-via-api) but more or less the reverse.

I am using the fql "thread" object in combination with an XMPP chat to add some messaging/inbox functionality to a client side app.  I notice if the user adds a message to a thread via XMPP, the "unseen" field in the fql "thread" is switched off.  My question: Is there a way to send some form of message/element to chat.facebook.com that will switch the "unseen" field to off short of sending an actual message.  Thanks!

I have tried;

```
<message type="chat" to="-fbid@chat.facebook.com">
 <active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"></active>
</message>
```

Also tried to trick the service with;

```
<message type="chat" to="-fbid@chat.facebook.com">
 <composing xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

Even tried to send a dummy message with empty body;

```
<message type="chat" to="-100004885119811@chat.facebook.com">
 <body></body>
</message>
```